# Метод Filter, вывод

Tags: javascript, массивы, filter

Обьясните пожалуйста, как работает метод filter данном примере. Если я правильно понимаю, то этот метод возвращает массив, который подходит по условию, которое задано. Так вот, в примере возвращаются единицы, почему работает именно так? Если я передаю в качестве аргумента item, (пусть это будет двойка из массива), ее индекс будет == 3, получается item == 2, index == 3, далее должно работать условие: (indexOf(item) === 3 !== index(3)) === false по идее двойка вылетает, тут все правильно. Но почему в таком случае остаются единицы, если это же условие срабатывает и на них?
Прошу сильно не пинать, я еще совсем новичок

````
    let repeated
    return repeated = arr.filter((item, index) => arr.indexOf(item) !== index)
    // return arr.filter((item)=> item !== repeated[0])[0]
}

console.log(findUniq([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]));```
````

Comment: "Но почему в таком случае остаются единицы, если это же условие срабатывает и на них?" --- условие срабатывает как false лишь на одной из единиц (на самой первой)....на остальных будет true, поэтому они остаются

Comment: Хорошо, второе условие получается - Индекс второй едииницы равен 1, я спрашиваю, не равен ли он индексу этого элелемента (то есть единице), мне возвращается false типа 1 !==1 == false, Тогда и вторая единица должна улететь. И почему остальные элементы независимо от значения точно так же вылетают, то есть остаются только единицы. Я правда пытаюсь понять как это работает.

Comment: почему вторая единица должна улететь, если `indexOf(1)` **ВСЕГДА** будет возвращать 0 ?

Comment: Да да, именно этого я и не понимал, теперь разобрался. Спасибо огромное!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Суть примерно такова:

`indexOf` возвращает первое найденное вхождение элемента в массиве. Когда в первый раз встречается число, результат `indexOf` совпадает с индексом текущего элемента. Если же число встречается не в первый раз, то его индекс отличается от того, который возвращает `indexOf`

На вашем же примере: индекс первой единицы - 0, `indexOf` вернет тоже 0, т.к. это первое вхождение. На второй же единице индекс будет 1, а результат `indexOf` - все так же 0. Поэтому первая единица не попадет в итоговый массив, а все остальные попадут

Comment: Спасибо большое за разъяснение, буду думать.)

Comment: а почему на второй единице indexOf все так же 0? это же следующая итерация и indexOf второй единицы уже должен быть 1 и условие точно так же не должно выполняться. И вообще возвращаются только единицы, любые другие числа отсеиваются. Я пытаюсь сообразить что к чему, но никак не могу понять. Уже на листочке расписывать начал.

Comment: @psina, Дословная цитата с developer.mozilla.com: "Метод `indexOf()` возвращает **первый** индекс, по которому данный элемент может быть найден в массиве или -1, если такого индекса нет.". Вы на каждой итерации через `indexOf` ищете в массиве не сам элемент, а его **ЗНАЧЕНИЕ**, то есть единицу. Поэтому индекс текущего повторяющегося элемента будет отличаться от того, который вернет `indexOf`.

Comment: АААА... я видимо просто слишком тупой. Спасибо :)

Comment: Вот вот, теперь понял!!! Начал изменять первый элемент в массиве и начало доходить!!! Вот спасибо ребята! Помогли старичку! Всех обнимаю!